# Vimeo API not working for me

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo

UPDATED: The vimeo api is correct. My problem was silly, it was a caching issue. I was testing it in Chrome and hitting refresh and then thought.. maybe it's just a caching issue so I put it in IE and it worked ... then went back to Chrome, cleared the cache and it was fine :) Thank you everyone for your help... It helps me to talk through the issues to be able to see the problem more clearly :)

html file:

```
<body>

<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/15258975" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>


<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script src="https:/story_content/user.js"></script>

<script>
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

player.on('play', function() {

    alert("yay!");
});

player.on('ended', function() {

    alert("ended!");
    myFunction1();
});     


var callback = function() {};

player.off('play', callback);   

var callback2 = function() {};

player.off('ended', callback2);


    </script>



</body>
```

This is my user.js file:

```
alert("where are you!1");


function myFunction1(){
    alert("where are you!2");
//alert("inside!!!function 1");

var player = window.parent.GetPlayer();

    //2. var test1 = player.GetVar("pie");

var test2 = player.SetVar("test1",100); 

   //2.  alert(test1);

   return test2;

}// User defined code goes here
```

The first alert "where are you!1" runs so the html is calling my user.js file but the second alert: where are you!2 is not running so the myFunction1 is not running... then I put alerts in the Vimeo code in the html: player.on('play') and player.on(end') and they don't work.

But I know the Vimeo API is working because on my old http site it calls myFunction... just not on my new migrated https site...

http://[takenOut]/Branch%20Manager%20-%20Action%20Plans%20-%20Storyline%20output/story_html5.html

https://[takenOut]/kristen/branchingTest/Branch%20Manager%20-%20Action%20Plans_v1%20-%20Storyline%20output/story_html5.html

Thank you for the help.

Comment: seems you are trying to access parent JS from a iframe?

Comment: also there is an error in user.js url: https:/story_content/user.js it is missing one "/"

Comment: where are you calling - `myFunction1()`? You won't have access to it in your html file

Comment: Thank you for responding. The user file is fine... I know it is connecting fine from the html because my first alert pops up, so I know the problem is in the API.... but that's the strange part. The api worked fine (and still does on my old site) but is not on my new site (the alert within the player.on api function is not working).

Comment: Paul - the myFunction1 is on my user.js file... I tested and made sure the user.js file is being called and it is... so I think the problem is that the player.on and player.end is not working.

Answer (score 0):

oh, no... I feel dumb. It was a cashing issue. Thank you for your help Tanaydin and Paul Fitzgerald.

Comment: It would be helpful for future readers to edit this answer and also explain the steps you took to solve your caching issue

Comment: By "cashing" do you mean "caching"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, caching. I was testing it in Chrome and hitting refresh and then thought.. maybe it's just a caching issue so I put it in IE and it worked ... then went back to Chrome, cleared the cache and it was fine :) Thank you everyone for your help... It helps me to talk through the issues to be able to see the problem more clearly :)